# derivative of square root of quadratic form with respect to matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus

How would I go about calculating $ \frac{d\textit{$\alpha$}}{d\boldsymbol{A}}$
for $$\textit{$\alpha$} = \sqrt{\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}}$$
where $\alpha$ is a scalar, $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $\boldsymbol{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Sorry if this question is straightforward. I'm trying to implement an algorithm and came across this equation. I'm not familiar with matrix and vector derivatives. Also, any links to a comprehensive introduction to matrix/vector calculus would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you furnish a reference so we can see it in context?

Comment: Here's the [paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/papers/Old_papers/xing_nips02_metric.pdf). I am/was trying to implement 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^\top A x$ can be written as $\sum_i \sum_j a_{ij} x_i x_j$. In this form, it is not hard to see what the partial derivative with respect to $a_{ij}$ is for any $i,j$. Then $\frac{d}{dA}(x^\top A x)$ can be viewed as a matrix consisting of all such partial derivatives.

To deal with $\sqrt{x^\top A x}$ you can just use the usual chain rule with the map $z \mapsto \sqrt{z}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let us define the Frobenius product by a colon and use it's cyclic property
\begin{align}
{\rm Tr}\left( A^T B C \right) 
&:= A: BC \\
&= AC^T: B
\end{align}

So,
\begin{align}
\alpha = \sqrt{x^T A x} \Longleftrightarrow \quad \alpha^2 = x^T A x \equiv x: Ax.
\end{align}

Now, we can use differentials and then obtain gradient.
\begin{align}
2 \alpha d\alpha &= x: dAx \\
   &= xx^T:dA \\
\Longleftrightarrow  d\alpha &= \frac{xx^T}{2 \alpha} :dA = \frac{xx^T}{2 \sqrt{x^T A x}} :dA
\end{align}

The gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial A} = \frac{xx^T}{2 \sqrt{x^T A x}}.
\end{align}

Comment: +1 but you forgot $\,:\!dA\,$ on a couple of those differential expressions.

Comment: @greg Thank you so much for the feedback -- updated now.